# Is a lightning wallet registered in bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

Say, I create a wallet with an `lnd create` command. As everything is initially on Bitcoin blockchain, will the wallet address/metadata be written into blockchain?

So, can I find the address of my Lightning wallet in Bitcoin blockchain and send BTC in an old-fashioned way?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a channel with another party involves creating a 2-of-2 multisig address and sending funds there.  This is an an address where funds are controlled by both your lightning node and the other party according to the rules of the script with fallbacks that allow you to always receive back as much as you put in.

> can I find the address of my Lightning wallet in Bitcoin blockchain and send BTC in an old-fashioned way?

If I am understanding correctly, you would like to send an on-chain payment directly to the generated multisig address to add funds to **your** channel balance?

Sorry, that won't work as expected for a number of reasons... It sounds like you are looking for a [Submarine Swaps](https://docs.lightning.engineering/the-lightning-network/lightning-overview/understanding-submarine-swaps) which are trustless / atomic.

Edit: I see you are using `lnd`, so you can use [Loop In](https://lightning.engineering/loop/) for this purpose.